# Viewing source code of standard namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to be able to view the code running behind the scenes when I call specific functions in C# - is it possible to find and decompile these code libraries? MSDN often has usage examples and plain-text explanations, but in some cases I want to see code execution and which functions call each other.

As a specific example, I would like to crack open the `System.Web.UI.Page` class. How can I view the **source** code for this class, *not* the documentation?

Comment: Either ReSharper or VS alone can automagically download the sources from the [Microsoft Reference Source Code Center](http://referencesource.microsoft.com) when you navigate to a class), or decompiles the IL when it can't. You should be able to download the sources from that site too.

Comment: [Configuring Microsoft Reference Source Server](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/serversetup.aspx)

Comment: @millimoose ReSharper seems like a good tool to have, I downloaded the 30-day and will try it out. You mentioned VS natively has this ability? I am aware of the `go to definition` option on the context menu but it only exposes some comments for each method. Is there another?

Comment: @Zerkey The site I linked to has [setup instructions](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/serversetup.aspx). I also consider R# invaluable, but I have origins in Javaland where I used the Jetbrains IDE and got used to having the features around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the .NET Framework Reference sources from here:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

This includes most (if not all?) of the BCL libraries.. such as Dictionary, List, String, etc.

Answer (score 0):

During debug mode on,if you want to see decompiled code on the current cursor position in visual studio 2022, press `ctrl+F11`
This will take you to the current disassembly.